Apply multi-row UPDATE to SQL Server table from pandas DataFrame with one statement
I am trying to update Microsoft SQL Server table entries (using pypyodbc) with values from a pandas dataframe. Currently, I am creating a numpy array from the pandas dataframe, then iterating on each row of the array, using a unique ItemID to do an UPDATE WHERE ItemID = ? statement.
Is there a way to accomplish the below in a single UPDATE statement instead of looping on each record?
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10, 11], ['nick', 12, 13], ['juli', 14, 15]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

np_array = df.to_numpy()

query = """
        UPDATE table_A 
        SET Item1 = ?, Item2 = ? 
        WHERE ItemID = ?
        """

connection = pypyodbc.connect('<connection_string>')
cursor = connection.cursor()

for i in range(0,len(np_array)):
    itemID = np_array[i][0]
    item1 = np_array[i][1]
    item2 = np_array[i][2]

    params = (
            item1,
            item2,
            itemID,
            )
    cursor.execute(query, params)
    cursor.close

cursor.commit()
connection.close


maybe you should use execute_many - like execute_many(query, data) without using dataframe, numpy, and for-loop.

as  I remember DataFrame should have function to send data directly to database - like df.to_sql(...)

When you say "SQL table" do you actually mean "Microsoft SQL Server table"?

@GordThompson Yes.

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or newer you can use OPENJSON(), like so:
data = [['tom', 10, 11], ['nick', 12, 13], ['juli', 14, 15]]
# give the columns meaningful names
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ItemID", "Item1", "Item2"])

sql = """\
UPDATE table_A SET table_A.Item1 = df.Item1, table_A.Item2 = df.Item2
FROM table_A
INNER JOIN
OPENJSON(?) WITH (
    ItemID nvarchar(50) '$.ItemID',
    Item1 int '$.Item1',
    Item2 int '$.Item2'
) AS df
ON table_A.ItemID = df.ItemID
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (df.to_json(orient="records"),))

